# How do I get this hat?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

This is a grey hat that he wears earlier in the story. You can get most of his clothes from earlier in the story but I haven't found out how to get this hat.

John's Hat
[image: Johns hat]

Comment: The answer to this question might be a spoiler but the question certainly isn't. I don't see any value in hiding the very item being asked about here. I have not completed RDR2 and this has not spoilt anything for me. Answers should employ spoiler tags if required.

Answer (score 1):

To get John's gamblers hat you need to during the epilogue part 1 have it knocked of and be picked up again. YOU CANNOT REPLAY MISSIONS TO GET IT. So sorry if you have already completed the epilogue.